# Application Loader Error - Google Plus SDK & Beackons SDK while submitting app to app Store

Tags: ios, app-store, google-plus, ibeacon, application-loader

I am trying to upload application(`ipa` File) on `appStore` from `Application Loader`, using `Xcode 7.0.1`. I have used - `Google Plus SDK` & `Beackons SDK`. Now while submitting app its giving me following error -

[image]

I have tried to find it on google but didn’t found effective stuff.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this problem, I came up with this solution -

1) Remove `CFBundleExecutalbeKey` from respective `plist` file.

2) Set Device type to `iPhone` rather than `iPhone-Simulator` in respective `plist` file.

In my case, it was Beacons SKD & Google SDK.